# how to force all users on Windows server 2019 to open .csv file using Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to set Excel as the default app for all users on Windows server 2019 to open file extensions with .csv.

please assist.

Comment: I do not think you can stop a user from opening a CSV file using (say) Notepad.  People can generally select the app they wish to use.

Comment: in the file explorer, right click on any file and choose Open with.  Then choose Choose Another App.  Then before you choose Excel click the check box to make that the default.  But I think that is by user and as such each user would need to do it.  But as noted, any user can also use Open With to select anything they want and I do not think you can turn that off.

Comment: I need help with forcing everyone as default to open CSV file in Excel

Comment: There is no way to "force" users to use Excel and only Excel as the program for csv-files unless you wanna lock down the whole system, which I assume is not what you wish to do.

Comment: Please concider adding more detail to your question my editing it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the free
[SetUserFTA](https://kolbi.cz/blog/2017/10/25/setuserfta-userchoice-hash-defeated-set-file-type-associations-per-user/).

The syntax is :

```
SetUserFTA.exe extension progid (optional:Groupname)
```

To find out which is the progid of Excel, you could run in a
Command Prompt (CMD) this command:

```
assoc | find ".xlsx"
```

For Office 2019 and 365 this should give : `Excel.Sheet.12`.

The command to use will be similar to the following, to operate on all users:

```
SetUserFTA.exe .csv Excel.Sheet.12 "Users"
```

(Note : I haven't tested this utility on my computer.)

Comment: I tested the command not taking effect.